# Check in Kotlin a collection of obejcts all properties are null but one property is set

Tags: list, kotlin

How to check in Kotlin in a collection (e.g. List) of obejcts all properties are null but one property is not null and is set in a perfomat way.

Here is an example, but this is ugly if the data class object has a lot of properties.

```
data class Person(val name: String?, val age: Int?, val address: String?)

val people = listOf(
    Person("Mary", 20, "Street 111"),
    Person(null, 22, null),
    Person(null, 21, "Street 123")
)

val filteredAgeOnly = people.filter{ it.address == null && it.name == null && it.age != null }
```

`filteredAgeOnly` should contain only the second item with age = 22.

If if the data class would have more properties, then the filtering must be touched and extended everytime with `&& it.newProperty == null`.

Comment: I suspect this is a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Checking for exactly one non-null property is a rather weird thing to do. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I've updated the question. the returned list should contain Objects, where only the age is set but nothing else.

Comment: As Sweeper says, knowing some of the bigger picture would help here. What does it _mean_, in business terms, for exactly one attribute to be set? (Does it indicate a particular type of `Person` object, e.g. one that could be a super/subclass or alternative implementation?)

Comment: I don't know what I can add here. What it should do is to return a list of people where only `age` is set and everything else is not. And instead of querying every single property of the class for null and `age` for not null, I'm looking for a performant way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a helper method - this is the easiest and most-effective way of doing this (but, as you have noticed, you must add `prop == null` each time a new property is added).

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String?, val age: Int?, val address: String?) {
    fun allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge(): Boolean {
        return name == null && address == null && age != null
    }
}
```

Then there would be only one place where you need to apply such a change. And I think this is a preferred way.

**Bonus:**

You can use reflection to write such a method. But remember about the potential overhead (and kind of overengineering) while using such an approach:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

data class Person(val name: String?, val age: Int?, val address: String?) {

    fun allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge(): Boolean {
        // verify age is not null:
        if (this.age == null) {
            return false
        }

        // get all properties except age and verify them:
        // please notice those are only declared member properties,
        // if you need to check extension properties as well do another check with `declaredMemberExtensionProperties` property
        val memberProps = this::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter { it.name != this::age.name }
        return memberProps.all {
            it.getter.call(this) == null
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
fun main() {
    val p = Person(null, null, null)
    val p2 = Person("abc", null, null)
    val p3 = Person("abc", 10, "def")
    val p4 = Person(null, 10, null)

    println(p.allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge())
    println(p2.allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge())
    println(p3.allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge())
    println(p4.allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge())
}

// prints:
// false
// false
// false
// true
```

You can use such a method in filtering too:

```
val allPersons = listOf(p, p2, p3, p4)
val ageOnly = allPersons.filter { it.allPropertiesAreNullExceptAge() }
```

Comment: thanks this is explaining what I want to do, but instead of returning Boolean, it should return a list of Persons where only `age `is set.

Comment: Added example of using the method in filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you can use:

```
data class Person(val name: String?, val age: Int?, val address: String?){
    fun hasNonNullAttributes(): Boolean {
        return listOf(name, age, address).all { it != null }
        // -----------------------------^ add other attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest a method on `Person`! (In fact, I was half-way through writing a comment when you posted this :-) If you had access to the `Person` class, it could be a direct method instead of an extension method, especially if it seems like an inherent attribute of a person that you might want to reuse elsewhere.

Comment: (I see you edited this answer to remove an alternative solution using reflection. That was ingenious — but reflection is also slow, ugly, insecure, fragile, hard to read, hard to debug, etc., and best kept only for cases such as frameworks, plugins, and build tools where it's really needed. So probably best not to suggest it here!)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, instances of data classes with equal properties are considered to be equal so this is what you can do.

First, make all properties optional by providing a default value of `null`, like

```
data class Person(val name: String? = null, val age: Int? = null, val address: String? = null)
```

Then you can do

```
val filteredAgeOnly = people.filter{ it == Person(age = it.age) }
```

When you add new properties make sure to make them optional, then this line can stay the same.

Comment: But still, while adding any property to Person class, someone would need to fix this line as well. And this is what OP would like to omit.

Comment: @Cililing true. Though it might be a cleaner solution than before

Comment: @Cililing I changed my answer to account for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it dynamic you could use reflection to check the member properties if they are null:

```
val filteredAgeOnly = people.filter { person ->
    person::class.memberProperties.filter { it != Person::age }.all { it.getter.call(person) == null } && person.age != null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "filter instance" of a Person like this:

```
val compareToPerson = Person(null, 0, null)
```

And then filter the list by comparing local copies created by the built-in data class copy method:

```
val result = people
  .filter { it.copy(age = compareToPerson.age) == compareToPerson }
```

The value of the property (or properties) to filter on is irrelevant, it just has to be non-null. In this case I use 0.